# How do I get text from a Swift textView?

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to learn Swift. In Java (my 'home' language), if I have a JTextField *a* and I want to get its contents, I simply call

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
String output = textField.getText();
```

How do I get text from a similar component in Swift?

EDIT: This is all in OSX, not iOS.

Comment: Take a look at the Swift language guide to familiarize yourself with the Swift language and its syntax: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: I think you should be consistent in what you are asking here. Your title asks for textView but your post asks for textfield. They are two different things.

Answer (score 10):

simple just do this code:

create an outlet for your text view then:

```
output = textView.text
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Set up your `UITextField` through the `Interface Builder` ;
2. Link it to your controller code file with drag/drop, you should then have a property : `@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextView!` ;
3. Access the property you're looking for : `myTextField.text` (you can set it to a variable, for example : `var myString : String = myTextField.text`).

That said, you might want to read the documentation (at least the basics) : http://goo.gl/TJfMGT

Then, if you're interested by `UITextField` in particular, you'll find it's class reference here : http://goo.gl/jMEas0

Comment: I should clarify. I'm attempting to do this for OSX, not iOS. Edited question to reflect that. In OSX, I do not believe there is such a thing as UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can get the plain text from the macOS text view (NSTextView) in Swift (I added also an example for NSTextField).

First create an outlet for the field in Interface Builder editor. Remember that the outlet of a NSTextView has to be made from the "Text View" object which is embedded in two other objects: Scroll View -> Clip View -> Text View.

Then you can use this code to get the plain text

**NSTextView:**

```
let myText = myTextView.string
```

In case you have a TextField instead of a TextView:

**NSTextField:**

```
let myText = myTextField.stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(textField.textStorage as NSAttributedString!).string
```

The problem is NSTextView, rather than IOS.So you should use the method to get the above