# Superimpose a user filled out UITextView over an image with CGRect, not the same as combining two images?

Tags: swift, swift3

I've been using this function to combine two images together using CG rect:

```
 let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: frame.bounds.size.width, height: frame.bounds.size.height))

        img = renderer.image { ctx in


            let someSize = CGSize(width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height)



            currentImage.scaleImageToSize(newSize: someSize).draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 35, width: frame.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))



            //textView?.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.bounds.size.width, height: textView.bounds.size.height))


            frames = UIImage(named: framesAr)
            frames?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.bounds.size.width, height: frame.bounds.size.height))

        }
```

I use this CGRect function to combines the currentImage (UIImage) and frame(UIImage) into a single UIImage no problem, but my attempts to add in a text view in the same fashion doesn't seem to be working.

I have a UITextView in front of an image for testing purposes. My hope was to be able to type text in the textView and use the commented out line in the above function to draw the entire textView and its contents in place.

When the image is saved the function runs, but the textView is simply ignored. Googling yields results on how to add strings to images, but not a user fillable textview in this fashion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've never seen this kind of thing work - but that's nothing new! One thought... you are using CG to draw in a UIView, right? But you **can't** simply "draw" a UITextView because it **is** a view. Have you added it as a subview to this UIView?

Comment: Im still relatively new to swift, I'm not sure what you mean by adding the UITextView as a subview to the UIview. I added the textview in IB and set its constraints in IB as well.

Comment: That's what I meant. Adding it in IB infers that it is a subview of the main view. Your code... (1) It works, as in it is using CG to draw the image(s) in what we'll call the "main" view. (2) Understanding that all you are doing is "drawing" in a CGRect that is **not** a subview of any sort - therefore, not requiring constraints because it's the main view that has them - what exactly is the issue you are seeing (um, or not)? Is your textView not there at all? Is it not where you want it? I'm thinking you are combining things the use auto layout and do not.

Comment: Im not seeing the textview all at when the above function runs and the "textview" line is uncommented.

Comment: One more comment. You are doing two things here. First, your are doing CG **drawing** inside one view (the main view) which is constrained using auto layout. This main view exists within a view hierarchy that includes this textView, which all views should also have constraints defined. (Consider this: you see both the main view and the textView in IB but you don't see the image nor an imageView there, right?) Second, you are trying to use CG to "draw" this textView like this image (or combined image). This is a totally different thing than adding it in any way to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Yet one more thing! :-) You mentioned you are relatively new to Swift. This doesn't sound to me at all like it's related to what lunges you are coding in - it goes deeper. It's UIKit (Cocoa Touch) and Foundation (Cocoa). Views, hierarchies, drawing, etc. Don'r get stuck on how to change your coding - think in terms of why the view you are trying to draw (which is what I meant by saying "'I've never seen this kind of thing work") isn't drawing. You can't just "draw a view using Core Graphics. (But you can draw images **on** a view.) I hope this helps.

Comment: currentImage(UIImage) and frame(UIImage) were both also done in IB (placed and constraints). so currently the image and frame draw, combine and save correctly. the textview is sitting on top both of them in IB but doesn't show on the exported image when the function is ran.

Comment: No, currentImage and frame are UIImageViews, not UIImages. Big difference. What exactly is the end product? A UITextView with a combined image as the background?

Comment: right! I meant UIImageView. the end product is a textview filled with user inputed text on top of an image, then the whole thing is exported as a new image.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Given the question - the answer is **no**, superimposing a UITextView (which is probably not possible) over an image - no matter how constructed - is **not** the same as combining two images. But give me a some time to "think outside of the box". Hint: my first thought is to subclass some things to be a single control, and if not, work with CI/CG to manipulate graphics within (yep) a subclass. Hopefully someone else has something for you before me....

Comment: thanks for the advice! I'm stuck at the moment and some of what you said went over my head "subclass some things to be a single control" so I'm going to keep researching but ill be checking back here often to see if you responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founds a way that works, but its more of a workaround than anything else.

setup your textview like ichamps answer from this question:

[How do I get text from a Swift textView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996434/how-do-i-get-text-from-a-swift-textview)

then print the contents of the textview onto the image like this:

```
     let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .left

            let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir book", size: 14)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]



            let string = "\(myString)"
            string.draw(with: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.bounds.size.width, height: frame.bounds.size.height), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)
```